# How to remove these straight lines when plotting?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I did a python optimization with 4 design variables and many trials for varying each design variable. The results of each trial are updated to a master dataframe.

To see the effect from each design variable, I am trying to plot different subsets of the master dataframe, where I hold 1-2 variables constant and vary the others. Then I plot using matplotlib.

When I plot the results, I see this weird straight line connecting the start and end points of my curves:

[image]

I want to remove this line. Note that I am successful in plotting contours for different design variables, so I think I'm confident I am correctly parsing the master dataframe to create the subset dataframes I am plotting

[image]

Perhaps there are outliers in my data, but when I filter/sort my CSV in excel, I do not see these straight lines. Any tips?

this is how I am parsing the dataframe to plot, using df.loc[]:

```py
ax1.plot(df.loc[(df['some_var_1'] == 24) & (df['some_var_2'] == 0.001), 'some_var_3'], df.loc[(df['some_var_1'] == 24.0) & (df['some_var_2'] == 0.001), 'output'])
```

the contour plots were successful perhaps because I only kept one value constant at a time?:

```py
ax1.tricontour(df.loc[(df['some_var_1'] == 24.0), 'some_var_2'] * 1E3,                 df.loc[(df['some_var_1'] == 24.0), 'some_var_3'] * 1E3,                 df.loc[(df['some_var_1'] == 24.0), 'output'],                 levels=30, cmap='inferno')
```

PS is there a better way to view a multi-dimensional optimization problem than with contour plots? I am still searching for an alternative

Comment: Is your data sorted? Those lines are there because matplotlib connects successive points in the data frame, which it seems are at very different x-values.

Comment: Welcome. Missing input data for [mre]